# how to restrict unfollow users from accessing the blog content using if-statement in django templates?

Tags: django, templates, if-statement

Guys i want to create a logic for Django in the template where only the subscribed users can access the blog post. i tried to use only_for subscribers boolean field  and user.followers group to allow post only accessible for subscribers.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique=True,default=None)
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add = True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='uploaded_by')
    published = models.BooleanField(default=True)   
    only_for_subscribers = models.BooleanField(default = False)

    @login_required
    def ArticleDetailView(request,slug):
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
        return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'post': post,})


class Contact(models.Model):
    user_from = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='rel_from_set')
    user_to = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='rel_to_set')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} follows {}'.format(self.user_from, self.user_to)



    User.add_to_class('following', models.ManyToManyField('self', through=Contact, related_name='followers', symmetrical=False))


{% if request.user not in user.followers.all and post.only_for_  
subscribers %}
Please subscribe
{% else %}
<div>
{{post.title}}
</div>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a user modele and defined permissions classes for your groups of users you can use either one of these tags
using authentication to allow view of specific content
`{% if user.is_authenticated %}`
`<!--There got your the html section you want the user to see only if he is authenticated -->`
`{% else %}`
`<!-- provide a behavior if not you can redirect to login page for instance -->`
`{% endif %}`
Using permissions to allow specific actions
`{% if user.is_staff %}`
   `{% if perms.your_module.your_set_permission %}` 
    provide a link to your view
   `{% endif %}` 
Hope this help!